# Remove a White Space Text Node/Link

Tags: javascript, html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am currently working with SharePoint 2013 to try and hide a single link out of 5 links on the sidebar of the webpage. I can successfully remove the link by using this code:

```
var sideLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item-text");
sideLinks[2].parentNode.removeChild(sideLinks[2]);
```

Which removes the link, but leaves an area of white space that contains a reference to the link I was trying to remove, so users can still click and go to that page. I believe this is a text node from other answers I have seen on here and elsewhere, but I don't know how to remove it. The problem is that `sideLinks` or that white space, which is an `li` element within a `ul`, when I inspect the source code do not have Id names, only class names. The class name of the ul containing the white spaces is: `zz12_RootAspMenu`, but I can't seem to use a `removeChild` on these white space items.

Is it possible to remove this with just javascript? I apologize if this is vague, I am not really sure what other information would be required. If anyone needs more information or can give me some links that would be amazing.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

If the item is a menu item provided automatically by Sharepoint, you can add/remove this items through the Site Configuration > Navigation.

Comment: Just a reference to help https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-the-top-link-bar-for-site-navigation-1B614211-2882-4507-A791-8716090C9905